# NoSuchMethodError (checkState) in CacheBuilder

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, guava

I have created a Guava (a library packed with useful stuff that can be very handy in almost any Java project, including libraries for immutable collections, functional programming, I/O and much more) CacheBuilder based cache

```
 LoadingCache<String, Byte[]> companyDevicesCache = 
             CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(1000)                     // maximum 100 records can be cached
                .expireAfterAccess(24, TimeUnit.HOURS) // cache will expire after 30 minutes of access
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Byte[]>(){ // build the cacheloader

                   @Override
                   public Byte[] load(String companyId) throws Exception {
                      //make the expensive call
                      return getFromServletContext (companyId);
                   }


                });
```

I've tried also

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
         .maximumSize(1000)
         .build(new CacheLoader<String, List<String>>() {
             @Override
             public List<String> load(String queryKey) throws Exception {
                 return null;
             }
         });
```

and also

```
CacheLoader loader = new CacheLoader()
            {
                public String load(String key) throws Exception
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public Object load(Object arg0) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            };

         LoadingCache<String, String> persons = CacheBuilder.newBuilder() 
                 .initialCapacity(30) 
                 .maximumSize(40) 
                 .recordStats() 
                 .build(loader);
```

and

```
final LoadingCache<String, Optional<Product>> cache =


               CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                   .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                   .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .build( new CacheLoader<String, Optional<Product>>() {
                         @Override
                         public Optional<Product> load( String productId ) throws Exception {
                             return null;
                         }
                   }
             );
```

But when I init the CacheBuilder I got this error:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
        at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(CacheBuilder.java:409)
```

this is the version of the library: `guava-20.0-rc1.jar`

Here the libs included in the ear

[image]

I also tried to replace the library for this one `guava-19.0.jar` but then I got

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.common.base.Equivalence, but class was expected
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Strength$1.defaultEquivalence(LocalCache.java:393)
        at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.getKeyEquivalence(CacheBuilder.java:297)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:246)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4868)
        at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(CacheBuilder.java:786)
```

Comment: Where does this 20.0-hal version come from? It's not an official Guava release ([GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava/releases), [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.guava%22%20AND%20a%3A%22guava%22)). Are you sure you don't have multiple versions of Guava on the classpath?

Comment: download an official Guava release, clean everything with the same result :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really looks like you have multiple versions of the `com.google.common.base.Preconditions` class on the classpath (maybe from a reeeeally old google-collections jar?), or a corrupted jar.

The [method overload](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v20.0-rc1/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L503) which isn't found has been [added in Guava 20.0](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/892e323fca32945cdfb25395ca6e346dd0fffa5b):

```java
public static void checkState(boolean b, @Nullable String errorMessageTemplate, long p1)
```

based on the signature in the `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
           ||                 | |
           ||                 | returns void
           ||                 |
           ||                 long
           |String
           |
           boolean
```

You can find where your class definition comes from by adding the following code before your call to `CacheBuilder.maximumSize()`:

```java
System.out.println(com.google.common.base.Preconditions.class
        .getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource()
        .getLocation()
        .toExternalForm());
```

You'll get the URL of the jar.

I've downloaded `guava-20.0-rc1.jar` from Maven Central, extracted its content and inspected the content of `Preconditions.class` using `javap`, and the method is definitely there:

```
$ javap Preconditions.class
Compiled from "Preconditions.java"
public final class com.google.common.base.Preconditions {
  // ...
  public static void checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, long);
  // ...
}
```

---

In your ant snippet, there are multiple wildcard includes, such as:

```xml
<include name="**/spring/*.jar"/>
```

There might be an extra version of Guava in there, especially considering the other error you get when switching to guava-19.0: `Equivalence` was an [interface](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v9.0/src/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.java#L34) until 9.0, and was changed in [2011](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/46d4eb45009051a9c1d212c26ee4567db3e9c34d#diff-dfa67d14401779cd90c9c6587bc6e0adR38) to a [class](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v10.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.java#L41) for 10.0.

Comment: conflict with com.google.common_1.0.0.0_0-6.jar file from weblogic-home/modules